# How to show current schema of running queries in postgresql 13

Tags: postgresql, schema

I use multi-schemas in one database in Postgres,such as

```
Postgres(instance)
  MyDB
    public
    MySchema1
      table1
      table2
    MySchema2
      table1
      table2
    MySchema3
      table1
      table2
```

And It's open to my users,my users will run queries,
such as
User1:

```
set search_path=MySchema1;
select * from table1,table2;
```

User2:

```
set search_path=MySchema2;
select * from table1,table2;
```

User3:

```
set search_path=MySchema3;
insert into table3 select * from MySchema1.table1,MySchema2.table2;
select * from table3;
```

I want to show current schema of running queries,But pg_stat_activity can only show database name, not schema name.

I want current schema (search_path ) as

| datname | username | schema | query |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MyDB | User1 | MySchema1 | select * from table1,table2; |
| MyDB | User2 | MySchema2 | select * from table1,table2; |
| MyDB | User3 | MySchema3 | insert into table3 select * from MySchema1.table1,MySchema2.table2; |

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the current setting of a parameter for another database session.

I recommend that you use the parameter `application_name` for that:

```
SET search_path = myschema1;
SET application_name = myschema1;
```

The current setting of `application_name` for another database session can easily be queries from `pg_stat_activity`.